# Yaml fixtures of java playframework doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, yaml, ebean, fixtures

I tried to make the [zenTasks](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaGuide2) tutorial for the play-java framework (I use the current playframework, which is 2.3.2). As it comes to testing and adding fixtures I'm kind of lost!
The docu states that

```
Edit the conf/test-data.yml file and start to describe a User:

- !!models.User
    email:      bob@gmail.com
    name:       Bob
    password:   secret
...
```

And I should download a sample (which is in fact a dead link!)

So I tried myself adding more Users like this:

```
- !!models.User
    email: somemail1@example.com
    loginName: test1

- !!models.User
    email: somemail2@example.com
    loginName: test2
```

If I then try to load it via

```
Object load = Yaml.load("test-data.yml");
if (load instanceof List){
    List list = (List)load;
    Ebean.save(list);
} else {
    Ebean.save(load);
}
```

I get the following Exception:

> [error] Test ModelsTest.createAndRetrieveUser failed:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This bean is of type [class
>   java.util.ArrayList] is not enhanced?, took 6.505 sec [error]     at
>   com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.saveRecurse(DefaultPersister.java:270)
>   [error]     at
>   com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.save(DefaultPersister.java:244)
>   [error]     at
>   com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.save(DefaultServer.java:1610)
>   [error]     at
>   com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.save(DefaultServer.java:1600)
>   [error]     at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.save(Ebean.java:453) [error]
>   at ModelsTest.createAndRetrieveUser(ModelsTest.java:18) [error]
>   ...

How Am I supposed to load more than one User (or whatever object I wish) and parse them without exception?

Answer (score 1):

In `Ebean` class `save` method is overloaded.

1. `save(Object)` - expects parameter which is entity (extends `Model`, has `@Entity` annotation)
2. `save(Collection)` - expects collection of entities.

`Yaml.load` function returns objecs which can be:

1. Entity
2. List of entities

But if we simply do:

```
Object load = Yaml.load("test-data.yml");
Ebean.save(load);
```

then `save(Object)` method will be called. This is because at compile time compiler doesn't know what exactly will `Yaml.load` return. So above code will throw exception posted is question when there is more then one user in "test-data.yml" file.

But when we cast the result to `List` as in code provided by OP then everything works good. `save(Collection)` method is called and all entities are saved correctly. So the code from question is correct.

Comment: Note that the save() method WAS overloaded but that is not the case in newer versions of Ebean.  In a newer version of Ebean you use saveAll() for saving a collection of entity beans.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with loading data from "test-data.yml". But I have found solution for this problem. Here is http://kewool.com/2013/07/bugs-in-play-framework-version-2-1-1-tutorial-fixtures/ solution code. But all *Ebean.save* methods must be replaced with *Ebean.saveAll* methods.

Comment: Please copy the relevant parts of the answer into your text here.  That way if the blog post ever becomes unavailable, the answer isn't lost.